# How to extract the string variable in android?

Tags: android, string, string-formatting

```
String test=["1","Low-level programming language",true]
```

Here i want to extract this string value and as i need to get only second value like "Low-level programming language".How to get this value using string functions in android?

Comment: That doesn't look like legal Java. What is your _actual_ programming problem?

Comment: i have one string value =["1","Low-level programming language",true].i want to get only second value.

Comment: So the string is [`"[\"1\",\"Low-level programming language\",true]"`](http://ideone.com/pxo3Ko)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, I'm assuming that you have a single string that contains the entire text (including the brackets). In general, splitting comma-separated values is a fairly tricky process. For your specific string, though, it's kind of easy:

```
String test = "[\"1\",\"Low-level programming language\",true]";
String[] pieces = test.split(",");
String middle = pieces[1];
// now strip out the quotes:
middle = middle.substring(1, middle.length() - 1);
```

In general, you might want to look at using a general CSV parser like [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) or [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Alternatively, if this is JSON data (which looks more likely than CSV), take a look at using one of the Java JSON libraries listed [here](http://www.json.org/) (scroll down the page to see the list).